# pulling rows with a max(column) value but with regards to being smaller than another column in SQL

Tags: sql, left-join

I have two different data sets but I want to append the columns of one onto the other based on it's date being the max date that is STILL less than the date in the other dataset in SQL.

Example Table 1)

```
|  ID  |  date  |  value  |
|  05  |  10/13 |   ab    |
|  10  |  10/15 |   sd    |
```

Example Table 2)

```
|  ID2  |  date2  |  value2  |
|  05   |  10/10  |   rf     |
|  05   |  10/23  |   tx     |
|  10   |  10/01  |   jk     |
|  10   |  10/12  |   fr     | 
|  10   |  10/23  |   as     |
```

And the resulting table I want is:

```
|  ID  |  date  |  value  |  date2  |  value2  |
|  05  |  10/13 |   ab    |  10/10  |   rf     |
|  10  |  10/15 |   sd    |  10/12  |   fr     |
```

When I try to code it, I can't seem to get the correct result. I have tried something like this but I get an error:

```
    select
        t1.*
    into final
    from table1 t1
    left join 
        (select 
            ID2,
            date2,
            value2
        from
            table2
        Where max(date2 < date)) AS t2
    on t1.ID = t2.ID2;
```

Comment: The columns `date` and `date2` are not of type `DATE`, they are of type `VARCHAR`, so the comparison will work as for strings.

Comment: Also your query would not be executed, because you are trying to refer to the column of the outer query in the joined subquery

Comment: Even as a string, `'10/13'` is not a date, a date consists of day, month and year.

Comment: "but I get an error:" Alexey already pointed you to the source of the error, but if you get an error, why don't you tell us the error message?

Comment: Please TAG your speicifc RDBMS, a *lateral join* would make this easy.

Comment: Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you don't have dates in your sample data. If we pretend you indeed have dates such as those found in [this fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vTeh1Wvuz8KGtCBYiJTkP4/0), then the following could work where CTEs are used.

```
with max_date as (
 select t2.id, max(t2.date) as max_t2_date
 from table2 t2
 join table1 t1
   on t2.id = t1.id 
 where t2.date < t1.date
 group by t2.id
 ), 
max_date_value as (
 select t2.id, t2.value, mm.max_t2_date
 from table2 t2
 join max_date mm
   on t2.id = mm.id 
  and t2.date = mm.max_t2_date
 )
select t1.id, t1.date, t1.value, mdv.max_t2_date as date2, mdv.value as value2
from table1 t1
left join max_date_value mdv
  on t1.id = mdv.id
```

Output:

| id | date | value | date2 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05 | 2021-10-13T00:00:00.000Z | ab | 2021-10-10T00:00:00.000Z | rf |
| 10 | 2021-10-15T00:00:00.000Z | sd | 2021-10-12T00:00:00.000Z | fr |

There are likely shorter ways to achieve this but knowing the RDBMS is required. This could at least get you started and play around with different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `date` and `date2` columns are of the type `CHAR(5)` and stores values like `MM/DD`, to get the expected results you can use a query like this

```
WITH t2_rn AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id2 ORDER BY date2 DESC) AS rn2
    FROM table2
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM table1
        WHERE id = id2 AND date > date2
    )
)
SELECT
    id,
    date,
    value,
    date2,
    value2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN t2_rn ON id = id2 AND rn2 = 1
```

---

If you are using SQL Server then you you can use the `OUTER APPLY` operator, and the query will look like this

```
SELECT
    id,
    date,
    value,
    date2,
    value2
FROM table1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 
        date2, 
        value2 
    FROM table2  
    WHERE id = id2 AND date > date2 ORDER BY date2 DESC
) t2
```

---

Both queries have the same output

| id | date | value | date2 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 10/13 | ab | 10/10 | rf |
| 10 | 10/15 | sd | 10/12 | fr |

You can check a working demo with both queries [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=915e63abec8009d0b7898ca56f457ca1)